# Echo issue (Safari and Twilio Video API)

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I'm using the Twilio Programmable Video API and have run into audio echoing issues in a few circumstances. My particular implementation is pretty complicated, but I can actually duplicate this problem 100% of the time using the [js video quickstart project](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js) on github.

1. Follow the directions on the [readme](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js) to setup the application.
2. Use ngrok to publicly expose your application.
3. Open Safari and send the ngrok url to a friend to open in Safari.
4. If the participants aren't wearing headphones, both will get very loud pronounced echoing problems.
5. This issue doesn't seem to occur in Chrome.

I've messed with the audio settings quite a bit - the preferred audio codecs, turning off gain control, manually turn on echo cancellation - all of these seem to have an effect, but none fix the echoing issue in Safari.

What are the next steps in debugging? How can I make this echoing issue go away?